# Regex for replacing return xxxx; statements

Tags: javascript, regex

I am doing something unholy that requires me ro replace all occurrences of "return xxx;" in snippets of code with something else.

For instance

```
function(x, y)
{ 
 if(x == 0) return "bye bye";
 else
 return x+y;
}
```

Would become

```
function(x,y)
{
 if(x == 0) unholy("bye bye");
 else
 unholy(x+y);
}
```

Seeking for help as regex keeps defying my comprehension.

Edit due to "question is a duplicate of 'learning regex'":

although learning something new is always a great option, not necessarily it is always the best one. I would love to learn stitching wounds but while bleeding out it's better to just seek a doctor. Of course if I keep cutting myself all the time, or my job always puts me in the position of being cut - then I definitely need to learn stitching wounds. Moreover, sometimes learning goes through watching someone fix something, and seeing how they did it.

Comment: Try this: `code.replace(/return.*?[\n;]/g, 'unholy("shit")')`

Comment: @dfsq that would account for the parameters passed to unholy.

Comment: @biffen well then any question about X is a possible duplicate of "Learning X".

Comment: @ozgar yes in fact I got to that point, what I can't wrangle is how to wrap  unholy("   and     ")   around whatever is contained between   return    and     ;

Comment: @biffen this is a question about a specific case of regex, which doesn't necessarily imply "I don't want to learn regex". It' more "please show me how to solve this specific case, as I can't. And I will observe and learn". Also see my edit.

Comment: There are different levels of learning. I don't need to learn Spanish to be able to order a pizza in Spain. It's quite simple to learn that simple, specific phrase. And this is quite a simple task, so it wouldn't have taken you much time to google it. It's "Me gustaría una pizza, por favor." btw (according to google translate ;)

Comment: @ClasG depends.. unfortunately (not a joke) I am behind the great firewall of China, google is unaccessible without a VPN, bing is pretty much erratic, all websites pulling some javascript from google or fb are broken, etc. etc. ... I love doing my own research but here it's really challenging so for a quick itch like this I gave up to the temptation of just asking someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of several ways of doing it:

```
.replace(/return\s+([^;]*);/g, 'unholy($1);');
```

The regex finds any return statements and following spaces, then **captures** anything up to a `;`. Replacing the **full match** with `unholy` followed by the previously **captured** part inside parentheses does the trick.

The `g` after the regex stands for *global* and makes it repeat the replace through the entire text.

```js
var code =  'function(x, y)\n'+
            '{\n'+
            '  if(x == 0) return "bye bye";\n'+
            '  else\n'+
            '  return x+y;\n'+
            '}\n';
            
 console.log(code);
 
 code = code.replace(/return\s+([^;]*);/g, 'unholy($1);');
 
 console.log(code);
```

Comment: didn't know about the "capturing" mechanism. Looks like a chance for me not just to solve this but also clean up lots of other convoluted expressions. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Now you've learnt something without any bleeding ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't undustand question, but why you need regex? Something like this enough you.

```js
function(x, y) {
  function unholy(a, b) {
    if (typeof arguments[1] == 'string') {
      return "bye bye";
    } else return a + b;
  }
  if (x == 0) unholy("bye bye");
  else
    unholy(x + y);
}
```